# Accessing original 'this' when using .bind()

Tags: javascript, scope, bind

I've just started using `FUNCTION.bind(scope)` instead of making a scope alias.

I'm wondering if there is a way to access the original scope i.e. what this would have refered to so that I can use both of these scopes without creating a scope alias (`var scope = this;`)

```
// Example using a psuedo library
var scope = {
    load: function() {
        Request.ajax({
             url: '/api/thing',
             success: function(response) {
                   var data = this.convertToJson(response);
                   var config = ORIGINALSCOPE.getConfigData();
                   this.renderData(data, config);
             }.bind(this)
        });
    },
    convertToJson: function(json) {
        return JSON.parse(json);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: No way. If you want to have access for both - use closures instead of bind

Comment: Updated to include example

Comment: @VasilVanchuk: Make that an answer, please :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No way. If you want to have access for both - use closures instead of bind

P.S> in your case you can use `scope` inside function